# Excel/Google Sheets: How to have a conditional multiplier

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a multisheet that I need to do the following:

```
If 'UserInput'!A9=1, multiply the following formula's output by 1.5: 'Data'!A1*(('Data'!A2*'Data'!A3)+'Data'!A4)
```

[The sheet and cell names aren't particularly relevant.]

In other words, how could I add a conditional multiplier to an already-existing formula, without complicating user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this ...

`=IF('UserInput'!A9=1,1.5,1.0)*('Data'!A1*(('Data'!A2*'Data'!A3)+'Data'!A4))`

Or you could put this into, for example `'Data'!C1`

`=IF('UserInput'!A9=1,1.5,1.0)`

and modify your formula this way ...

`='Data'!C1*('Data'!A1*(('Data'!A2*'Data'!A3)+'Data'!A4))`